# Reducing euclidean TSP of smaller size to euclidean TSP of bigger size

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, approximation, traveling-salesman

Assume I have a euclidean TSP solver that is **optimal**, but it can only solve inputs with exactly $N$ vertices. Let's call it the **N-solver**.

Now, I have an input with $K$ vertices in the 2D plane, where $K < N$. Can I convert this $K$ sized input to an $N$ sized input where I can feed it into my N-solver and obtain an optimal answer, and then try to convert it back to an optimal solution for the original $K$ vertices?

**I assume that you are not allowed to have multiple vertices at the same coordinate.**

Has this problem been discussed, investigated, or solved anywhere? Even some approach that guarantees some gap compared to the optimal answer would be good. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add a set $FO$ of $N - K$ vertices *far out*? None should be included in an optimal answer.

Comment: @greybeard That was my initial thought. However, I need mathematical guarantee. Therefore, it begs the question: how far? Let's say we add those $N-K$ vertices in an infinite far distance. Since the answer is a tour, it passes through every vertex. Those far away vertices are also included (in other words, we have at least 2 transitions between the original $K$ nodes and those $N-K$ far away nodes). I couldn't guarantee any optimality gap for the path that is generated for the original $K$ vertices in this construction (since we need to add another edge to make a Hamiltonian cycle for them).

Comment: (Dang. Somehow I diverted from *cycle* to *shortest path*.)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152475/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51600/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a mathematical guarantee, you should run $k-1$ times the $N$-solver algorithm. In other words, repeat the following approach for each vertex $v_i\ \ i=2,...,k$ and take the best solution.

Introduce $N-K$ new vertices $V_j\ \ j=k+1,...,N$ on the line segment between two vertices $v_1$ and $v_i$; e.g. With distance $d_{1j}=(j-k)\frac{d_{1i}}{N-K+1}$ and $d_{ij}=d_{1i}-d_{1j}$. Then, if $x_{1i}=1$ in the optimal solution on $k$ vertices then on N vertices we have $x_{1,k+1}=x_{k+1,K+2}=...=x_{N-1,N}=x_{Ni}=1$ with a same optimal value .

But, if you want to execute the idea of @greybeard, find $d_{a,b}=max\{d_{ij}\}$ and add $N-k-1$ far away new vertices $V_j\ \ j=k+1,...,N-1$ on the left side of the line $v_a-v_b$; e.g. With distance $d_{aj}=(d_{a,b})^{10}+j$ and $d_{bj}=d_{aj}+d_{ab}$. Moreover, add a new vertex $v_N$ close to the vertex $v_a$ as much as it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that doesn't work: Assume K = N-1. Take any node X and create another node X' at a distance epsilon from X, and calculate all the distances to X', then solve the N problem. If that solution directly connects X and X', then removing X' gives an optimal solution for the original problem, otherwise move X' closer to X and try again.

You might get it to work if you pick an X at the outside of the graph so you can guarantee nobody will want to go to X or a very nearby place twice.